# jquery vs react.js remove item from a list

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

```js
const RenderItem = (props) => {
    return(
      <ul id="todo">
      {props.items.map((item,i) => 
        <li className='list-group-item' data-id={item.id} key={i}>{item.name}
        <button className="btn btn-sm btn-primary" onClick={() => props.remove(item.id)}>X</button>
        </li>
      )}
      </ul>
    ) 
};

const TodoItems = React.createClass({
  getInitialState() {
    return {
      items: [
        {id:1,name:"Gym"},
        {id:2,name:"Jump"},
        {id:3,name:"Racing"}
      ]
    }
  },
  remove(id){
  this.setState({
   items: this.state.items.filter((el) => id !== el.id)
  })
  },
  render(){
    return(
      <RenderItem items={this.state.items} remove={this.remove}/>
    ) 
  }
})


ReactDOM.render(
  <TodoItems />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://facebook.github.io/react/js/jsfiddle-integration-babel.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.24/browser.js"></script>

<script src="https://npmcdn.com/react@latest/dist/react-with-addons.js"></script>

<script src="https://npmcdn.com/react-dom@latest/dist/react-dom.js"></script>

<div id="container">
    <!-- This element's contents will be replaced with your component. -->
</div>
```

I'm confused how stuff work here in react.js, I need presduo code how to passing work. I was from jquery background, it's so straight forward, just get the right dom and do $(this).remove(), while in react I'm confused.

```
<button className="btn btn-sm btn-primary" onClick={() => props.remove(item.id)}>X</button>
```

When you click what happened? arrow function for? and where does the remove come from?

Answer (score 0):

React follows **unidirectional data binding**, which means, the data will flow in a single direction. So, the data is stored in a `state`. Whenever the `state` changes the component will `re-render`. A state can be changed at any point in time. But, mostly it will be changed on any `action`. In your case the action in `onClick()`. This will call the function will the `id` of the element which triggered the `onClick()`. Now, in that function, you will iterate through the `state`, identify, remove and set the new state using `setState()` which will re-render the component with the new data. This render will not have the clicked element as it was removed from the state.

The `remove()` function is passed on to the child component from the parent component which can be accessed using `props`. This will be a reference to the function declared in the parent component. During the click, using this reference, the function in the parent component will be called!

Answer (score 0):

In react, components are rendered based on their `props` and `state`. `props` are passed from the parent component, and a component may or may not have internal `state`.

Using jQuery, you would try to remove it by removing the DOM node directly. However, in react, interacting with the DOM directly is an anti-pattern. Since the current `state` and `props` determines what is rendered, you want to change one of those that will cause a re-rendering and display something new.

In your case, it looks like you're trying to modify `props` directly. `props` are read only and should not be modified. Since `props` are passed down from the parent component, you would have to change what's being passed down from the parent. There are a few ways you can do that, such as passing a callback function defined in the parent component as a prop that can make such a change. But for this example, it might be easier/more applicable to use `state`.

Remember, you want to change the component's `state` to reflect what you want to see (what you want to `render`). So let's say you have an array called `items` in your component's `state`. And let's say you are

```
class ListDemo extends React.component {
  constructor() {
    super()

    // initialize state
    this.state = {
      items: ['thing1', 'thing2', 'thing3']
    }
  }

  onClick(index) {
    // newItems is a new array with the element at the given index removed
    // this logic doesn't handle edge cases, but that's besides the point
    const newItems = [
      ...this.state.items.slice(0, index),
      ...this.state.items.slice(index + 1)
    ]

    // here we set this component's state's items to 
    // the new state with what we want removed.
    // it will then re-render the component to reflect the new state
    this.setState({
      items: newItems
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {
          // here we render buttons for each item in the component's state's items
          // we use `onClick` to make it so that clicking the button
          // will remove it from the list
          this.state.items.map((item, index) => {
            return (
              <button 
                onClick={() => this.onClick(index)}
                key={`${item}${index}`}
              >
                {item}
              </button>
            )
          })
        }
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Let's go over what is happening in this example. First, when the component is created, it's initial `state` is set with an `items` array that contains 3 elements. When it is first rendered, it will create a button for each element in the `items` array. Notice that what is rendered is purely determined by the `state`.

Each button also has a callback that is called when it's clicked (set by `onClick`). This callback is what will remove that specific element from the `items` array and then update the component's `state` to have a new `items` array without the element that was just removed. This in turn causes a re-rendering, which uses the new `items` array to display the buttons. This time around, the button we removed by click it is no longer there since it's no longer in `this.state.items`.

That is one of the key concepts of react - components are rendered based on their `props` and `state`, and changing either will update what is displayed.

As for why to use an arrow function, it's because it will automatically `bind` the `this` value to the `ListDemo` component. Similarly, you can use something like `onClick={this.onClick.bind(this)}`. Doing this is necessary since the value of `this` when clicking the button isn't guaranteed to what you expect. Reading [this](https://medium.com/@rjun07a/binding-callbacks-in-react-components-9133c0b396c6) might make it more clear.